# Java Program to sort

Tags: java, mergesort

I'm trying to implement a code to mergeSort a list. I was told to use `getFirst()` and `addAll()` but I don't know how so this is what I came up with:

Also, I can't use a `void` for `mergeSort` method - because it gives me an error so I have to return something.

***Any suggestions will be very appreciate***

Comment: As edited, this is basically a "write me some code" question.  That is "too broad".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close in terms of getting your approach working.  Here's what I came up with.  I changed the logic to create new lists to contain the results at each level rather than creating new lists when you break up a list.  There's no reason to copy a list just to keep it in the same order.  It's the list in the new order that needs to be fresh storage.  This limits the number of copies and I think makes the logic easier, since you can then just append onto the end of each result list instead of having to have logic to set the right position in each list.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;

class Test {

    public static LinkedList<Integer> mergeSort(LinkedList<Integer> list, int start, int count) {
    
        if (count < 2) {
            LinkedList<Integer> result = new LinkedList<>();
            result.add(list.get(start));
            return result;
        }

        int size1 = count / 2;
        int size2 = count - size1;

        LinkedList<Integer> list_1 = mergeSort(list, start, size1);
        LinkedList<Integer> list_2 = mergeSort(list, start + size1, size2);

        return merge(list_1, list_2);
    }

    public static LinkedList<Integer> merge(LinkedList<Integer> list_1, LinkedList<Integer> list_2) {

        LinkedList<Integer> result = new LinkedList<>();

        int i = 0, j = 0;
        while (i < list_1.size() && j < list_2.size())
            if (list_1.get(i) < list_2.get(j))
                result.add(list_1.get(i++));
            else
                result.add(list_2.get(j++));
        while (i < list_1.size())
            result.add(list_1.get(i++));
        while (j < list_2.size())
            result.add(list_2.get(j++));

        return result;
    }

    public static LinkedList<Integer> mergeSort(LinkedList<Integer> list) {
        return mergeSort(list, 0, list.size());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Integer> myList = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(22, 45, 1234, 77, 4, 1111, 999, 12, 88, 44, 7777, 22, 33, 44, 666));
        LinkedList<Integer> sorted = mergeSort(myList);
        System.out.println(sorted);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
[4, 12, 22, 22, 33, 44, 44, 45, 77, 88, 666, 999, 1111, 1234, 7777]
```

UPDATE: As @rcgldr points out, the above solution doesn't meet the stated guidelines.  With this new version of the `merge()` method, the guidelines are met.  Note that this doesn't make the algorithm much more efficient (both versions create lots of lists and are quite INEFFICIENT), but it does save a bunch of walking to random positions in lists in favor of working from the front each list:

```
public static LinkedList<Integer> merge(LinkedList<Integer> list_1, LinkedList<Integer> list_2) {

    LinkedList<Integer> result = new LinkedList<>();

    while (list_1.size() > 0 && list_2.size() > 0)
        if (list_1.peek() < list_2.peek()) {
            result.add(list_1.getFirst());
            list_1.remove();
        }
        else {
            result.add(list_2.getFirst());
            list_2.remove();
        }
    result.addAll(list_1);
    result.addAll(list_2);

    return result;
}
```

Also note that calling `getFirst()` and then `remove()` is redundant.  `remmove()` can be called by itself to both grab the next element and remove it from the list.  I went with calling both methods to meet the requirements.

Comment: list.get(i) indexes into an linked list as if it was an array, rather than the original post suggestion of using getFirst(), where it seems the intent is to only operate on the first elements of  lists when reading, and only appending when writing.

Comment: @rcgldr - I don't disagree.  I was taking the first step for the OP of getting a working solution that was doing what their code was attempting to do.    Maybe your answer can move the OP further along. I wanted to avoid doing all of the work for the OP.

Comment: Please don't provide answers to bad questions. It encourages the use of SO as a coding service.

Comment: @siride - As originally presented (the code is gone now...don't know why), I don't see this as a terrible question. Often, students ask only for the answer.  Here the OP did they could and then asked for our help.  Isn't that what we are constantly asking for?  We say "make an effort and show us what you've got".  Isn't that what the OP did here? I didn't give a perfect new solution. I just took the OPs code and made it a little better...made it work and showed the OP where they went wrong.  It was a progressive answer to get the OP thinking and moving forward.  I don't see what's wrong here.

Comment: @siride - or are you only responding to the current state of the question?  If so, then I see your position.  Know then that there was substantial, structurally acceptable code in the question when I presented an answer.  My answer was based on that code.

Comment: @CryptoFool Yes, I am responding to the current state. But it did have code, it looks like, so that would have been a little more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is an accepted answer, this code uses `getFirst()` and `addAll()` as mentioned in the original post, in what I assume is the intended purpose of this exercise. It uses a bottom up merge sort, which avoids the top down issue having to scan lists to find mid points to split lists.

The basic concept of a bottom up merge sort is two 1 node lists are merged to create a sorted 2 node list, two sorted 2 node lists are merged to create a sorted 4 node list, two sorted 4 node lists are merged to create a sorted 8 node list, and so on, similar to bottom up merge sort for arrays.

A bottom up merge sort uses a small array of lists (java), pointers to nodes (C), or iterators to nodes (C++) to hold the lists. For this example code, I use an array of 32 lists. For each member of array, the member is either null or refers to a list where the number of nodes for the list for array[i] has 2^i nodes: array[0] 1 node, array[1] 2 nodes, array[2] 4 nodes, ..., array[30] 2^30 = 1 billion nodes. The last member will have 2^31 = 2 billion nodes or more if the total number of nodes is >= 2^32 (4 billion) nodes.

Nodes are removed from the front of the source list one at a time and each node from the source list is used to create a list `mm` with 1 node, then `mm` is merged into the array, stopping at the first null encountered:

```
    while(source_list not empty){
        mm = source_list.removeNode(()   // mm = next node from source list
        for(i = 0; i < 32; i++){         // merge mm into array
            if(array[i] != null){
                mm = merge(array[i], mm)
                array[i] = null
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
        if(i == 32)    // if i == 32, there is no array[32], so 
            i = 31     //  use array[31] instead
        array[i] = mm
    }
```

The pattern looks like this:

```
mm = next node from source list  // 1 node list
array[0] = mm

mm = next node from source list  // 1 node list
mm = merge(array[0], mm)         // 2 node list
array[0] = null
array[1] = mm

mm = next node from source list  // 1 node list
array[0] = mm

mm = next node from source list  // 1 node list
mm = merge(array[0], mm)         // 2 node list
array[0] = null
mm = merge(array[1], mm)         // 4 node list
array[1] = null
array[2] = mm
```

Once the last node is merged into the array, all the lists in the array are merged to form a single sorted list:

```
        mm = empty list
        for(i = 0; i < 32; i++){
            if(all[i] != null){
                mm = merge(all[i], mm);
                all[i] = null;    // (for garbage collection)
            }
        }
```

Java's native double linked list class doesn't provide a means to move nodes within a list or between lists, so a node has to be deleted when an element is retrieved from the front of a list, and a node has to be created when an element is appended to the back of a list, an extra overhead. In the case of C++ standard double link list class std::list, std::list::splice() can be used to move nodes within a list or between lists, reducing the overhead, such as `dst.splice(dst.end(), src, src.begin())`, which moves the beginning node (first node) from `src` to the ending node (last node) of `dst`.

```
    public static LinkedList<Integer> merge(LinkedList<Integer> ll,
                                     LinkedList<Integer> rr)
    {
        if(ll.isEmpty())
            return rr;
        if(rr.isEmpty())
            return ll;
        LinkedList<Integer> mm = new LinkedList<>();
        while(true){
            if(ll.getFirst().compareTo(rr.getFirst()) <= 0){
                mm.add(ll.removeFirst());
                if(!ll.isEmpty())
                    continue;
                mm.addAll(rr);
                break;
            } else {
                mm.add(rr.removeFirst());
                if(!rr.isEmpty())
                    continue;
                mm.addAll(ll);
                break;
            }
        }
        return mm;
    }

    public static LinkedList<Integer> mergeSort(LinkedList<Integer> ll)
    {
        if(ll == null || ll.size() < 2)
            return ll;
        int i;
        final int ASZ = 32;                 // create array (of nulls) 
        LinkedList<Integer>[] all= new LinkedList[ASZ];
        // merge nodes into array
        LinkedList<Integer> mm;
        do{
            mm = new LinkedList<>();        // mm = next node
            mm.add(ll.removeFirst());
                                            // merge mm into array
            for(i = 0; (i < ASZ) && (all[i] != null); i++){
                mm = merge(all[i], mm);
                all[i] = null;
            }
            if(i == ASZ)                    // don't go past end of array
                i--;
            all[i] = mm;
        }while(!ll.isEmpty());
        // merge array into single list
        mm = new LinkedList<>();
        for(i = 0; i < ASZ; i++){
            if(all[i] != null){
                mm = merge(all[i], mm);
                all[i] = null;
            }
        }
        return (mm);
    }
```

---

test code, takes about 3 to 5 seconds to sort 4 million (2^22) nodes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int COUNT = 4*1024*1024; 
    LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<>();
    Random r = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        ll.addLast(r.nextInt());
    long bgn, end;
    bgn = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ll = mergeSort(ll);
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("milliseconds " + (end-bgn));
    // check sort
    int i;
    i = ll.removeFirst();
    int j = i;
    while(!ll.isEmpty()){
        j = ll.removeFirst();
        if(i > j)
            break;
        i = j;
    }
    if(i == j)
        System.out.println("passed");
    else
        System.out.println("failed");
 }
```

---

In the merge code, I'm getting faster and more consistent run times using a loop instead of addAll, from 3 to 5 seconds down to 2.8 to 3.2 seconds, but the assignment states to use addAll.

```
                //  mm.addAll(rr);    // replace with loop is faster
                do
                    mm.add(rr.removeFirst());
                while(!rr.isEmpty());
```

Comment: Maybe you can explain what this is doing?   I can't figure it out, so I expect that the OP won't be able to either.  It appears that you'll create at least as many lists as there are items to be sorted, since each time you pull an item off the original list, you create a new list to hold it.  Seems you'll call merge() at least that many times also, and it creates a list each time.  So, without running your code, I'm guessing that it creates at least twice as many lists as there are items to be sorted.  That doesn't seem very efficient or practical to me.

Comment: @CryptoFool - I added an explanation to my answer.